# Edit Admin templates

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is it possible to edit the admin panel templates using plugins or in another way without touching the vendor directory?

I need to change the order of fields in order editing. Using plugin, editing the frontend is very simple, but I don't see such an option for the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine, I just had to rebuild

```
./bin/build-administration.sh
```